Chromium Kiosk Mode on Raspberry Pi 4 Crashes.. shows "Aw Snap..."
I’m running a Raspberry Pi 4 with Debian and Chromium in kiosk mode. The Pi handles a significant amount of data through Modbus/MQTT via another controller that has an energy meter connected to it. The controller sends voltage measurements and other data to the Pi, and I also send signals to control HVAC systems connected to that controller.
Everything is managed through a remote monitoring system with a React frontend and a Django backend. We use various protocol converters for Modbus, SNMP, MQTT, and other protocols, so a lot is running on the Pi. The RMS runs locally on the controller, effectively operating an entire telecom site via the controller. Data is stored in InfluxDB on the controller.
The Issue:
After approximately 14–15 days of operation, Chromium displays the “Aw, Snap” error on the screen. I’ve noticed that simply refreshing the screen resolves the issue. Additionally, if I access the controller remotely and navigate to its IP address, the RMS web page works fine—it’s only the Chromium screen that crashes and shows “Aw, Snap.” Reloading the page restores normal functionality.
I suspect the issue may be related to RAM usage or a buggy JavaScript code causing heap memory to be fully utilized, as my frontend is heavily based on React, making it difficult to review and debug.
When “Aw, Snap” occurs, I can still see Chromium processes running in the background using pgrep chromium.
I experimented by running different applications on Chromium until the RAM usage reached 100%, which caused the controller to restart. This might be due to a watchdog running in the background, but I’m not certain since other developers also work on this platform.
What I’m Looking For:
I would like to automate the recovery process so that when “Aw, Snap” appears, the screen either auto-refreshes or the Chromium process restarts automatically. This is important to prevent customers from becoming alarmed when the error occurs.
Questions:
Has anyone experienced a similar issue with Chromium in kiosk mode on a Raspberry Pi?
What are the best methods to automatically detect and recover from Chromium crashes in this setup?
Are there any recommended tools or scripts that can help monitor Chromium and restart it if it crashes?
How can I better identify the root cause of the crash, considering the potential RAM usage or JavaScript issues?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
